# URL encoding in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, urlencode

Is there a way to URL encode fields in SQLite directly in the query?

(somehow this question doesn't meet "*quality standards*" so I'll throw in an example query:)

```
select urlencode( field ) from table;
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting that to do?

Comment: This is not the job of the database really. Let alone the database as simple as SQLite. Pretty sure you would have to do that in the code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Specifically, I am trying to query an SQLite database created by Google Chrome containing a list of usernames and passwords (see http://thebigbrowser.blogspot.com/2012/04/linux-export-chrome-passwords-to-csv.html) and export it to a CSV file that I can then use to import into Firefox using this add-on https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/password-exporter/ however the fields need to be url encoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the [sqlite function list](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html), I didn't find anything that would do the job. But you can construct such a function manually as follows:

```
select replace(replace(replace(replace(field,
    " ", "%20"),
    "/", "%2F"),
    "(", "%28"),
    ")", "%29")
from table;
```

This version escapes four of the more common problematic characters. It's a quick-and-dirty solution if your data set does not contain many unsafe characters.

Answer (score 3):

SQLite does not support URL encoding out of the box.

But you can add URL encoding/decoding functions with the [`sqlean-crypto`](https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean/blob/main/docs/crypto.md) extension.

For example:

```sql
select load_extension('crypto.dll');

select encode('/search?q=sql+is+awesome', 'url');
-- %2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dsql%2Bis%2Bawesome

select decode('%2Fsearch%3Fq%3Dsql%2Bis%2Bawesome', 'url');
-- /search?q=sql+is+awesome
```

The extension also supports other encoding algorithms like Base32, Base64 and Base85.

Answer (score -2):

If the target is web browser, you can use javascript to achieve that like below:

```
select '<a href=# onclick=''window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text="+encodeURIComponent(" Welcome '||CustomerName||'"), "_blank").focus();''>wtsup</a>' wtsup2 from customer_table ;
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that. You should never output user data directly to the browser without properly escaping it first. You're just asking for an XSS attack.